# how to intentionally make it the table more bloat (more dead tuples)

Tags: postgresql

table tenk1: [source](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/95f5a7a42c048ec01ba2650496296fe88aacd50f/src/test/regress/expected/test_setup.out#L118)

```
create table    tenk_copy (like tenk1 INCLUDING ALL);
insert into     tenk_copy select * from tenk1;
alter table     tenk_copy set (autovacuum_enabled = false);
ALTER TABLE     tenk_copy   SET (autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.9);
select relname, relowner::regrole, reloptions   from pg_class pc    where pc.relname = 'tenk_copy';
```

return

```
  relname  | relowner |                          reloptions
-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 tenk_copy | test     | {autovacuum_enabled=false,autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0.9}
(1 row)
```

```
--1
begin;
update tenk_copy set unique1 = unique1 + 1;
update tenk_copy set unique1 = unique1 - 1;

update tenk_copy set unique1 = unique1 + 1;
update tenk_copy set unique1 = unique1 - 1;

update tenk_copy set unique1 = unique1 + 1;
update tenk_copy set unique1 = unique1 - 1;

update tenk_copy set unique1 = unique1 + 1;
update tenk_copy set unique1 = unique1 - 1;

update tenk_copy set unique1 = unique1 + 1;
update tenk_copy set unique1 = unique1 - 1;
commit;
```

```
select  * from pgstattuple('tenk_copy') \gx
```

return

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]------+---------
table_len          | 31080448
tuple_count        | 10000
tuple_len          | 2680000
tuple_percent      | 8.62
dead_tuple_count   | 100000
dead_tuple_len     | 26800000
dead_tuple_percent | 86.23
free_space         | 614216
free_percent       | 1.98
```

run the `--1` query again. then query the pgstattuple.

```
select  * from pgstattuple('tenk_copy') \gx
-[ RECORD 1 ]------+---------
table_len          | 59326464
tuple_count        | 10000
tuple_len          | 2680000
tuple_percent      | 4.52
dead_tuple_count   | 100000
dead_tuple_len     | 26800000
dead_tuple_percent | 45.17
free_space         | 28363688
free_percent       | 47.81
```

with 20 updates `dead_tuple_count` only 100000. I guess it means more unused space created, how can I config to make it actually have more dead tuples.

Comment: What is the structure of `tenk` (or `tenk_copy`)? Please put this information **as text** in the question itself and not as a comment - notify me by comment.

Comment: @Vérace in the first link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once no one cares about the tuple anymore, its space can be freed.  The line pointer pointing to the tuple can't be freed, it is just turned into a tombstone (so that indexes pointing to it know to ignore it).  A vacuum is not needed to convert the tuple into a tombstone, it is just needed to remove the tombstone itself.  Apparently pgstattuple doesn't count tombstones as being part of dead_tuple_count.

> how can I config to make it actually have more dead tuples.

Do more updates in the same transaction, or open a new session and begin a transaction which holds its snapshot and then keep it open.  But why do you want to?

Answer (score 1):

`VACUUM` was run on the table.  If indeed `autovacuum_enabled=false` (double check!), it could only be one of these:

- someone ran `VACUUM` on the table manually
- `autovacuum_freeze_max_age` was set to such a ridiculously low value that anti-wraparound autovacuum was triggered (which runs even when autovacuum is disabled). This should leave a log entry if `log_autovacuum_min_duration = 0`.